# Seeking ArcPy equivalent to IPixelBlock in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

Trying to figure out a way of doing this via ArcPy, but don't see anything remotely related to this.  My raster dataset is a GRID.

```
    'pPixBlock is an IPixelBlock

    'sets raster to be one column and one row in size
    pSizePoint.SetCoords(1, 1)

    pPixBlock = praster.CreatePixelBlock(pSizePoint)
```

Comment: arcpy is not meant to be feature-equivalent to ArcObjects. What exactly is the desired end result? You might be able to use [numpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) for it.

Comment: If you want to look at the value of a single pixel (rather than a block) then have a look at the _Get Cell Value_ tool?

Answer (score 3):

If you want extract a portion of a raster to a numpy array, you can use [RasterToNumPyArray](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/RasterToNumPyArray/000v0000012z000000/)

The other way around you can create a numpy array and write the value's to a raster: [NumPyArrayToRaster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/NumPyArrayToRaster/000v00000130000000/)